# C - execvp() second argument

Tags: c, unix, execvp

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1])
```

What exactly is done with the second argument of execvp()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument should be a pointer to a `NULL`-terminated array of strings, which becomes the `argv` of the called process.

The first element of this array becomes the `argv[0]` of the callee, which is not necessarily the same as its path; e.g., you can call a process by its full path, but pass it its basename as `argv[0]`. Also, some programs behave differently based on their `argv[0]`. The famous example is that Unix shells behave as "login shells" when their `argv[0]` starts with a `-`, so a primitive `login` program could do

```
char *argv[2] = {"-sh", NULL};
execvp("/bin/sh", argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is passed to the called program as it's `argv` vector. I [quote the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp):

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.